# R/apple problem: error in table() : all arguments must have the same length

Tags: r, macos-monterey

I am currently working on an R package, in which I want to build a list of frequency tables of each column of a matrix. When testing on a

macOS Monterey Version 12.6.3 (21G419)

using

R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) -- "Shake and Throw"
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

the following problem occurs (here reduced to an MWE):

```
test = matrix(sample(1:5, 1000, TRUE), 100,10)
str(test)
# int [1:100, 1:10] 4 4 2 5 3 1 2 4 5 1 ...

apply(test, 2, table, simplify = FALSE)

Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) :

   all arguments must have the same length
```

On a newer apple and on a windows machine, the code ran without a problem, hence it seems to be associated with the old version. My problem: I'd like to make the package also available to users of the older version rather than demanding an update.

Is anyone aware of a solution/workaround? The code seems correct and the matrix has no missings, factors, or other peculiarities. Why would such an error be thrown?

Comment: Weird, can't reproduce it, though. What if instead you built on `apply(test, 2, tabulate)` or faster `matrixStats::colTabulates(test)` instead?

Comment: `apply` gained the `simplify` argument only in R 4.1.0. In older R version, the argument would be passed to `table`. Personally, I would just depend on R >= 4.1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Roland stated in the comments, `apply()` gained the simplify argument in R 4.1.0. The [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply) for earlier versions show:

```r
apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, …)
```

The `...` argument is defined as:

> optional arguments to FUN.

This means that `apply(test, 2, table, simplify = FALSE)` is translated as:

```r
apply(test, 2, function(x) table(x, simplify = FALSE))
```

As `simplify` is not a named argument to `table()`, it is absorbed into the ellipsis and assumed to be a named vector. You are therefore doing something like:

```r
table(1:10, 0)
```

Hence the error message: `all arguments must have the same length`.

To circumvent this, you can use [`asplit()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/asplit) on [R `3.6.0`](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=test%20%3C-%20matrix(sample(1%3A5%2C%201000%2C%20TRUE)%2C%20100%2C%2010)%0Alapply(asplit(test%2C%202)%2C%20table) and greater to split the matrix into a list of columns, and then iterate over it:

```r
lapply(asplit(test, 2), table)
```

On versions earlier than `3.6.0`, e.g. [`3.5.2`](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyS1uETBViE3saQos0KjODG3ICdVw9DKVEfB0MDAQEchJCjUVRPM0TE00OTiykksKMip1CguyMks0QBp1lEozslMTtXLzEtJrYCKGGkCtZQkJuWkAnVw/f8PAA) you can do:

```r
lapply(split(test, slice.index(test, 2)), table)
```

Comment: Thanks to you and @Roland, for the excellent explanations and for the helpful alternatives.